# Are there any resources on how to use Visual Studio Team Services?

Tags: azure-devops

I work at a startup which until now was just me as the sole developer.

Now we are starting to build a team it's time to get project planning, sprint & task planning, proper source control etc. sorted out.

We have MSDN and free Visual Studio Team Services so I thought I'd try that.

However it is really really unintuitive and I am struggling to find on google how to use it.

I am looking at features and sprint stuff and wondering how I am supposed to use it.

I also linked it to my Visual Studio but I created a work item in visual studio and can't find a way to sync it back so it appears on the Visual Studio Team Services page.

Any ideas? Am I doing it all wrong?

If anyone can explain how the Features and Backlog thing works that would be so helpful.

Our system is divided into several areas, one of them is for the customer portal. So a typical bit of work would be, on the customer portal, in the Administration section, we need a way to view all registered users.

So do I create a feature for Customer Portal with a sub feature for Administration and put it in there? Or do I create a Work Item for Customer Portal Administration View Users or something?

It needs to be manageable so my boss can look at what's going on, who is doing what etc. and nicely divided up. But honestly I am at a total loss of how to configure it. All I can find guide-wise is a bunch of marketing gumf on youtube and no real-life use case tutorials.

Please help! :(

Comment: this question is probably way too broad, but If you decide to go with VS than MSDN offers a network of forums and online documentation, just check that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have some great walkthroughs at https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/overview that should get you started. In there you will find details on connecting with VS, using backlogs, taskboards, etc.

For case studies, here are a couple of links.

- http://www.microsoft.com/casestudies/Microsoft-Visual-Studio-Online/Humanitarian-Toolbox/Visual-Studio-Online-Used-to-Energize-and-Optimize-Crowdsourced-Development/710000004013
- http://www.microsoft.com/casestudies/Microsoft-Visual-Studio-Online/Eovendo/Cloud-Based-Load-Testing-Produces-Cost-Effective-Scaling-for-Ad-Rating-Service/710000003474

Comment: Cheers. In the end I created features as 'As a sysadmin I want to be able to manage users', then created backlog items as each thing I wanted to be able to do eg. 'I want to be able to reset a users' password' and then tasks under that for what needs to be done, eg.' I need a button that will trigger a password reset'